# How to use GET method when url rewritten in MVC (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using MVC pattern in `PHP` and rewrite urls this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Now the problem is i wanna to use `$_GET` method and when I use `?` after this character doesn't show in result for e.g:

```
http://localhost/site/register/?Authority=716&Status=NOK
```

Now the result after rewrite is : site/register/

I wanna to have all of link for use :

```
$Authority = $_GET['Authority'];
$Status= $_GET['Status'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L, QSA]
```

the QS flag tells apache to append the existing query string.

see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thanks but it does some result yet :( .   Your mean is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L, QSA]` ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion @mh-cbon ؟

Comment: have you restarted the server ? Can you enable rewritelogs ?

Comment: No i have n't any access